# Override current project with complete new rewrite

Tags: git

I have a project on git. Now I rewrote the project from scratch and nou want the current version on git to be completely over written by the new project.

What would be the way forward without having to create a new git repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current repository, you can do this:

```
git checkout master
git rm -r *
# tar or cp or whatever to move your new version into place
git add -A .
git commit -m "complete rewrite of project"
```